# Jquery function with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments, datetime-format

here I have a function that will show time based on div object width in jquery tooltip.

Now I want to use the same function to calculate "start time" and "end time" but I want to use the same function, not to write new, so I must create this funcion to be with arguments, but logicaly I dont really understand how to make it happend.

SO: in tooltip I must show:

```
var time = $( this ).width();
 var startTime = $( this ).position().left;
 var endTime = startTime + time;
```

also here is tooltip code:

```
$(document).tooltip({
        items: ".draggable",
        track: true,
        content: updateTooltipContent
    });
```

and function in which I must add argument:

```
function updateTooltipContent() {
    var time = $(this).width();
    if (time < 0) {
        time = 0;
    }

    var seconds = time % 60;
    var minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
    var output;

    if (minutes >= 10) {
        output = "" + minutes;
    } else {
        output = "0" + minutes;
    }
    output += "h ";
    if (seconds >= 10) {
        output += seconds;
    } else {
        output += "0" + seconds;
    }

    return output + "min";
}
});
```

Now the tooltip must show: `"spending time" + time + "start time" + startTime + "end time" + endTime;`

How to make this function with argment to use 3 times becouse I must convert number into time format ?

Comment: What do you mean, "with argument"?  What argument? What is the argument for?

Comment: function (time,startTime,endTime)...

Comment: I can write 3 functon but why when I can write just one..

Comment: What 3 functions would you write?

Comment: function update () var starTime ... function update1 var endTime ...

Comment: so I only need to convert number that I get from witdh and so. into time

Comment: I 3 times need to convert numbers into tim format so why to write 3 diferent function that do the same work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand what you're asking, but if it's just that you need the "updateTooltipContent" function to use a time formatter, you'd do this:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".draggable",
    track: true,
    content: function() {
      return formatTime($(this).width()) + formatTime(whatever) + formatTime(somethingElse);
    }
});

function formatTime( time ) {
    if (time < 0) {
        time = 0;
    }

    var seconds = time % 60;
    var minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
    var output;

    if (minutes >= 10) {
        output = "" + minutes;
    } else {
        output = "0" + minutes;
    }
    output += "h ";
    if (seconds >= 10) {
        output += seconds;
    } else {
        output += "0" + seconds;
    }

    return output + "min";
}
```

Getting a time value from the width of an element seems bizarre, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".draggable",
    track: true,
    content: updateTooltipContent(a, b)
});

function updateTooltipContent(a, b) {
```

Comment: yes I know that, but how function then will be, how to add start and endTime to function... where? please write ad jsfiddle

Comment: I can write 3 function but want to try with one with arguments, sorry for my english

Comment: I 3 times need to convert numbers into time format so why to write 3 diferent function that do the same work